# Jquery Code completion in NetBeans IDE 6.9 is not working in Windows 7

Tags: jquery, netbeans, netbeans-6.9

I use **NetBean version 6.9.1**.
Code completion in NetBeans works for other programming langauges except jquery in my Windows 7... 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>` is added on header and Jquery works in all Browsers.

For example:
When I write `$("p:first").app` ,  `$("p:first").append()`  should appear in the drop down. But It does not appear.

How can I make code completion work in NetBeans? Please help.

Comment: I used non-minified version and all works fine.

Answer (score -1):

From the netbeans [documentation](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/js-toolkits-jquery.html) : trying using ctrl-space once you've started typing.